# Accessing Jtextfield from outer action listener

Tags: java, swing, class, actionlistener, jtextfield

I am trying to access JTextField text namely 'searchBox' from outer action listener created in outer class.

GUI:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*; 

public class MyFrame extends JFrame
{
   public int stat1_var;
   public int stat2_var;
   public int stat3_var;
   public String stat4_var;
   private int statX_bound = 50;
   private int statY_bound = 280;
   public String url;

/*
* @param width  The width of the frame.
* @param height The height of the frame.
* @param title  The title of the frame.
*/


public MyFrame(int width, int height, String title, int stat1_var, int stat2_var, int stat3_var, String stat4_var)
{
  this.stat1_var = stat1_var;   //threading var
  this.stat2_var = stat2_var;   //spiders var
  this.stat3_var = stat3_var;   //results var
  this.stat4_var = stat4_var;   //other var

  initUI(width, height, stat1_var, stat2_var, stat3_var, stat4_var);

  this.setSize(width,height);   //set frame size
  this.setTitle(title);     //set frame title
  this.setVisible(true);    //set visible
  this.setResizable(false); //disable resizable frame

}


private void initUI(int width, int height, int stat1_var, int stat2_var, int stat3_var, String stat4_var) 
{
      ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("background.jpg");//background image source
      JDesktopPane dp = new JDesktopPane(); //create desktop pane
      JLabel lbl = new JLabel(ic);  //create label
      JPanel transparentPanel = new JPanel(); //create a JPanel

      lbl.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);  //bounds for the background

      transparentPanel.setOpaque(false);  
      transparentPanel.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);//bounds for the panel
      transparentPanel.setLayout(null);//default layout
      setLayeredPane(dp);

      JTextField searchBox = new JTextField("http://", 40); //keyword search box
      searchBox.setEditable(true);
      searchBox.setBounds(250, 130, 300, 25);
      searchBox.setToolTipText("Enter domain to be crawled");
      transparentPanel.add(searchBox);
      searchBox.setActionCommand("url");
      searchBox.addActionListener(new listeners(this));


       JButton crawlBtn = new JButton("Crawl"); // search button
       crawlBtn.addActionListener(new listeners(this));
       crawlBtn.setBounds(555, 130, 80, 25);
       crawlBtn.setActionCommand("crawl");
       crawlBtn.setToolTipText("crawl domain");
       transparentPanel.add(crawlBtn);//end

      JTextField searchBox2 = new JTextField("", 40); //crawl url search box
      searchBox2.setEditable(true);
      searchBox2.setBounds(250, 160, 300, 25);
      searchBox2.setToolTipText("enter your keywords");
      transparentPanel.add(searchBox2);     //end

      JButton jumpBtn = new JButton("Jump!"); // search button
      jumpBtn.addActionListener(new listeners(this));
      jumpBtn.setBounds(555, 160, 80, 25);
      jumpBtn.setActionCommand("crawl");
      jumpBtn.setToolTipText("crawl domain");
      transparentPanel.add(jumpBtn);//end

      JLabel stat1 = new JLabel("Threads: " + stat1_var);  //stat labels
      stat1.setToolTipText("Threads");
      stat1.setBounds(statX_bound, statY_bound, 300, 25);
      statY_bound += 25; //place the label one place below 
      transparentPanel.add(stat1);

      JLabel stat2 = new JLabel("Spiders: " + stat2_var);  //stat labels
      stat2.setToolTipText("Spiders");
      stat2.setBounds(statX_bound, statY_bound, 300, 25);
      statY_bound += 25; //place the label one place below 
      transparentPanel.add(stat2);

      JLabel stat3 = new JLabel("Results found: " + stat3_var);
      stat3.setToolTipText("Results found");
      stat3.setBounds(statX_bound, statY_bound, 300, 25);
      statY_bound += 25; //place the label one place below 
      transparentPanel.add(stat3);

      JLabel stat4 = new JLabel("Status: " + stat4_var);
      stat4.setToolTipText("Status");
      stat4.setBounds(statX_bound, statY_bound, 300, 25);
      statY_bound += 25; //place the label one place below 
      transparentPanel.add(stat4);          

      dp.add(lbl,new Integer(50));  
      dp.add(transparentPanel,new Integer(350));

      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //close the app if close button clicked

} //end constructor

public void paint(Graphics g) 
{ 
  super.paint(g); //call superclass' paint method 
  g.setColor(Color.BLACK); 

} //end method paint 

} //end class MyFrame
```

And this is the outer class listener:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;

public class listeners implements ActionListener
{
    private MyFrame myframe;
    public listeners(MyFrame myframe){
        this.myframe = myframe;
        //String source = e.getSource();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String action = event.getActionCommand();

        if (action == "url")
        {
         myframe.url = searchBox.getText(); //<----- I am trying to obtain this from the gui
        }

    }
}
```

I am trying to obtain the searchBox text value(arrows above) to the url variable from GUI class. Can anyone please help me with this? I have been looking for the solution for 3 hours now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`getSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29) to obtain a reference to the `JTextField`

```
JTextField searchBox = (JTextField) e.getSource();
```

Comment: LOL! I totally missed that he was actually adding ActionListener to JTextField. +1 for very elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Declare your `JTextField` variable as instance var. (outside of `initUI` method) and create getter method. Then call it in your `listeners` class:

`myframe.url = myframe.getSearchBox().getText();;`

Other sidenotes:

1. Name your classes properly. Names of classes begin with upper cases.
2. Do not extend your class with `JFrame` if you are not going to override some methods or to define new methods.
3. DON'T use absolute positioning for swing components! Use proper layout manager.